# How to install the Sun Java JDK on Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I've tried to add the Canonical Partner repository, but I still can't find the `sun-java6-jdk` package. What is the right way to install the Oracle Sun JDK instead of OpenJDK on [Ubuntu 10.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29) (Maverick Meerkat)?

Comment: http://superuser.com/ question I think.

Comment: @zengr, I knew this was to be mentioned, but as @nulluserexception wrote, this is a programmers' question. Users (even those super) hardly care of this. Only a programmer will probably ever have such a question.

Comment: Maybe Ubuntu stackexchange site will know why they dropped Sun Java.  I guess they decided openjdk is good enough. I had no luck installing sun jdk but openjdk is fine for me.

Comment: @mattsmith as far as I know, Sun JDK is faster than OpenJDK. Eclipse works notably faster with it, for example. BTW I neer knew Ubuntu stackexchange site exists - thanks.

Comment: @Matt @Ivan I'm not *sure* Sun Java has been dropped, I *think* (or at least hope so) it's just not available in the partner repo, yet.

Comment: Early last year, I wrote an article for installing our free Pdf reader in Ubuntu. There I have explained how to [manually install JDK or JRE from the Java website](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=182&t=How_To_Install_Free_PDF_Reader_In_Linux#install_sun_java_runtime_jre_ubuntu_linux) bypassing APT.

Comment: Just to add, the standard JDK are not Sun (or Oracle) Java JDK any more, it's OpenJDK. So try to avoid using Sun Java JDK. As Sun doesn't exists any more and Oracle JDK are just another implementation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update (2010/10/01):** Yesss, [Sun Java Finally Uploaded To The Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Official Partner Repository](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/sun-java-finally-uploaded-to-ubuntu.html).

---

**Update (2010/09/27):** Readers might want to check [Sun Java6 Packages [updated]](http://www.shermann.name/2010/09/sun-java6-packages.html).  I still expect official packages to be available in the partner repos at releast time though.

---

For an unknown reason, the sun-java6-jdk are not *yet* available in the partner repositories.

So either downloaded the required packages from http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/s/sun-java6/ and install them with `dpkg -i`.

Or temporarily replace the maverick partner repository

```
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
```

by the lucid one (replace `maverick` by `lucid` in the above line, let me know if you need more help to do this). Then, install sun-java6. And revert the change.

Comment: I was afraid to chaotize my packages database (I've already had such unpleasant experience once) by using another version repos, and came with dpkg. Worked pretty fine (but "bin" and "jre" packages depend on each other, so I had to force). Another problem which could be caused buy versions incompatibility is that JAVA_HOME env. var was not defined automatically.

Comment: It's now called Intrepid, not Maverick

Answer (score 55):

Currently the Sun Java 6 packages are working fine now for **Ubuntu 10.10** and **10.04** users. It works fine for me.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sun-java-community-team/sun-java6

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Comment: My attempt wouldn't install sun-java6 (E: Unable to locate package sun-java) so I installed it thus:  sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-bin

Comment: This worked well but indeed I also needed to use apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

Comment: I tried those 3 commands, confirmed they all succeeded and then get: "Unable to locate package sun-java6"

Comment: This has worked for me however I had to execute "sudo apt-get install python-software-properties" first

Comment: Since ubuntu removed these packages from their partner repositories, you can use that repository indeed to install sun-java6-* packages.

But, if you don't specificly need that package, better see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: This does NOT work anymore. Check here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747789/how-to-install-the-sun-java-jdk-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/3997220#3997220

Comment: @JohnPristine thats a link to this question

Answer (score 23):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sun-java-community-team/sun-java6

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jdk
```

Comment: this is the first on the list that worked on the first try with the fewest commands.

Comment: Glad I could help. Was frustrating enough for myself.

Answer (score 16):

Installation:

for 10.10:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ maverick partner"
```

for 11.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ natty partner"
```

Continue with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
```

Use as default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Installing JDK:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Source code (to be used in development):

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-source
```

Source of these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: The advantage is that you'll automatically get the source code

Answer (score 11):

All you need to do is uncomment the two lines in /etc/apt/sources.list that refer to "partner"

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
# uncomment the two lines referring to "partner"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jdk
```

(I can't find the command add-apt-repository on Ubuntu 10.10, 64 amd ... even searching with apt-cache yields nothing)

Answer (score 7):

It is working fine for me, but with a different command:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/bin# sudo apt-get install sun-java6
```

Error message:

> Couldn't find package sun-java6.

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/bin# sudo apt-get install sun-java*
```

Bam, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to use the version in the Lucid partner repository. I did this in Lucid (I used the version from Karmic multiverse, before I realized it had been moved to the partner repo), and it worked fine. Not sure where it went in Maverick though.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you need the JDK itself. If so you can accomplish this with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sun-java-community-team/sun-java6

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

You don't really need to go around editing sources or anything along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sun-java-community-team/sun-java6

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop simply do this: *[Ubuntu - Installing Java](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000395.htm)*.

Answer (score 1):

If add-apt-repository it's not working try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

That package is required in order to execute that command, in my server it wasn't installed by default (Ubuntu server x64)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu reporsitories can be more useful

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes#Sun%20Java%20moved%20to%20the%20Partner%20repository

Answer (score 0):

Here are step-by-step instructions, *[How to install Sun Java JDK in Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat](http://www.rogerobeid.com/2011/02/13/how-to-install-sun-java-jdk-in-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/)*.