# Installing java SDK in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: java, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Sun JDK on Ubuntu 10.10 “Maverick meerkat”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747789/how-to-install-sun-jdk-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat)

Can any one suggest me how to install java sdk in ubuntu 10.10?

Comment: You can install the OpenJDK version which comes with ubuntu or the latest version from Oracle. Would you prefer one provided by ubuntu or a standard version you may have on other non Ubuntu 10.10 systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For openjdk, use

```
aptitude install openjdk-6-jdk
```

For sun distribution, see: [How to install Sun JDK on Ubuntu 10.10 “Maverick meerkat”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747789/how-to-install-sun-jdk-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat)

Answer (score 2):

Just run this:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Could be that apt can not find the package. In this case add 
this line to your **/etc/apt/sources.list** file:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/lucid partner
```

Comment: Assuming the correct repository is set up.

Comment: Absolutely! I was editing exactly this. Thanx.

Comment: This should be `maverick`, not `lucid`, though.