# Launching small java parsing application on ubuntu server

Tags: java, multithreading, html-parsing, ubuntu-server

I created locally a small multithreaded parsing application just to get acquainted with multithreading and jsoup parser library.

On the server I installed java as it was described in this question/answer "[How to install the Sun Java JDK on Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747789/how-to-install-the-sun-java-jdk-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat)".

Here are my source files:

- [ParseArtCoderExample.java](http://pastebin.com/cRYiMTVF)
- [ArtCodeCategoryThread.java](http://pastebin.com/WynCv17y)

It was really easy to launch this application via IDE, but how to do it via terminal with *.jar library I don't know.

Thanks to everyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you package your application as an executable jar file using your IDE? If so, then running it in a terminal might be as simple as:

```
java -jar MyProgram.jar
```

or even just double-clicking the jar file.

To learn how to package your program as an executable jar file, see this tutorial: [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/).

The manifest file in the jar file should contain an attribute that looks like this:

```
Main-Class: test.parsing.ParseArtCoderExample
```

Comment: And if I would like to launch my files without *.jar usage, then this will be much more difficult I guess?

Comment: Works perfectlly and easy. IntelliJ is great.

Comment: If it isn't in a jar, it's also not very hard: something like `java -cp . test.parsing.ParseArtCoderExample`, when you're in the base directory of the package.

Comment: Great. Thank you. Could I ask here in comments about database usage or it is better to do as separate question if I will not find an answer. Asking it since the question will regard same parsing application. I need to put parsed results into database.

Comment: Better ask it as a separate question; StackOverflow doesn't work well for conversations in comments.

Comment: Posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705874/trying-to-connect-to-mysql-database-with-jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

Get your IDE to export a jar file (not sure what IDE you are using) that has the `Main-Class` manifest set correctly and you should be good to just run `java -jar {jarfilename}`. Which IDE are you using?