# Trying to connect to mysql database with jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ubuntu-server

I have ubuntu server running on virtual machine locally and I need to connect to mysql database there.
Database is in place and jdbc driver too. The only problem is that only way at the moment for my connection can be something like `http://local/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=sandbox` and that can't be used in jdbc connection string.

Hope, that somebody can advise a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username", "pwd");
```

Replace `localhost` with the IP of your VM. You have to use something other than NAT for networking in your VM (like [Host-only, internal or bridged](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) assuming VirtualBox).

You probably have to configure your Ubuntu firewall to let the connection through.

Also, you have to set mysql up to accept connections from the outside.
In the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` edit bind-address to your ip:

```
bind-address            = your-vms-ip
```

Comment: I'm using a VMware Workstation and at the moment I replaced my url as `String url = "jdbc:mysql://my_vm_ip:3306/database_name";`, but I get `Details : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`. I guess this might happen exactly due to the firefall, but I read, that it is disabled by default or as you mentioned the network configuration might be the problem.

Comment: How is your Workstation "connected"? NAT? Bridged? Look at my edited answer, maybe it helps.

Comment: Yes. It did help. I asked similar question at SF, since I thought, that it would be more suitable place. Everything working now. Here is the other question http://serverfault.com/questions/291378/how-could-i-configure-my-local-server-to-allow-jdbc-connection-to-mysql

Comment: I was just wondering, because you added a bounty to the question.